# How to store results of a for loop to a dataframe given a specific column/row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with different signals and returns. I want to do the following:

1. Subset a specific signal
2. Calculate the annualized return
3. Store result to a dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv7m5.png)

My code looks like this:

```
years = range(1990,2019,1)
returns = pd.DataFrame(columns=signals)

for i in signals:
    signal_i = portbase[portbase['signalname'] == i] #Select single signal from dataframe
    
    for j in years:
        signal_i_j = signal_i[signal_i['year'] == j] #Subset single year from signal
        
        return_j = (((signal_i_j['return']/100)+1).prod() -1) * 100 #Calculate annualized return for signal i in year j
        
        returns.loc[j,i] #Add result to dataframe in column i and year j
```

Everything works except for the last part, where i want so save my results.
I want my dataframe to look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlwHi.png)

Signals as columns and Years as rows

**Edit:**
Using the following code works:

```
df = portbase.groupby(['signalname','year'])['return'].apply(lambda x: (np.prod(1+x/100)-1) * 100).reset_index().T
```

But my output is still not correct:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pislx.png)

I tried to convert my output to a dataframe, reset the index and now somehow transpose my signal column as row/header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
df = portbase.groupby(['signalname','year'])['return'].apply(lambda x: (np.prod(1+x/100)-1) * 100).unstack().T
```

Comment: Your solution works fine! The only thing is that my signals are now safed in rows and not columns. So 1st column are my signals, then in the 2nd are the years (1990-2019) and in the 3rd the annual returns. Do you know how to transpose the first column so that i have my signals as headers?

Comment: I've edited my question above. Unfortunately the .T does not transpose my signal column.

Comment: Unfortuantely it's still not working. I've updated the image in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

its possible using pivot_table for this.

```
signal_cols = ['signalname1', 'signalname2']##..
agg_func = lambda x: np.prod(1+x/100)-1)
result = my_df.pivot_table(index='year', columns=signal_cols, values='return', aggfunc=agg_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing is that it seems you are not using your calculations to save them. j and i are the signals and years.

From the top of my head the .loc() function is for accessing/reading rows and columns by their name.
So you're essentially trying to access the data of years and signals of returns.

You might have to put your results in **lists** and then make a data frame out of them.

I hope my answer has helped somewhat.